# mysql: slow query on indexed field

Tags: mysql

The `orders` table has 2m records. There are ~900K unique `ship-to-id`s.

There is an index on `ship_to_id` ( the field is`int(8)`).

The query below takes nearly 10mn to complete. I've run `PROCESSLIST` which has `Command` = `Query` and `State` = `Sending Data`.

When I run `explain`, the existing index is used, and `possible_keys` is `NULL`.

Is there anything I should do to speed this query up? Thanks.

```
SELECT 
  ship_to_id as customer_id 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY ship_to_id 
HAVING SUM( price_after_discount ) > 0
```

Comment: Without a where clause you aren't using the index. That query is going to do a full table scan, but if you need to look at every order in the table, that's what you're going to have to do.

Comment: How many rows are returned by the query?

Answer (score 4):

Does not look like you have a useful index. Try adding an index on price_after_discount, and add a where condition like this:

```
WHERE price_after_discount > 0
```

to minimize the number of rows you need to sum as you can obviously discard any that are 0.

Also try running "top" command and look at the io "wait" column while the query is running. If its high, it means your query causes a lot of disk I/O. You can increase various memory buffers if you have the RAM to speed this up (if you're using innodb) or myisam is done through filesystem cacheing. Restarting the server will flush these caches.

If you do not have enough RAM (which you shouldn't need too much for 2M records) then consider a partitioning scheme against maybe ship-to-ids column (if your version of mysql supports it).

Comment: If price_after_discount can be negative, you might want to modify that where clause a tad... or your business model.

Comment: @beiler . . . This is not equivalent to the original query.  As Tim points out, this produces different results when if the price can be negative.

Comment: Just changing it to `WHERE price_after_discount <> 0` should make it equivalent. How much that improves speed really depends on your data though.

Comment: I've submitted the `create index idxpad on orders(price_after_discount)`. It's still running ( `price_after_discount` is `float` ). I'll try the query as soon as it completes.

Comment: if there are negative prices the where clause will not work. It depends on whether or not that is the case. The main advice is still good though, limit the rows as much as possible before using having clause, and also try to load as much of the table into RAM (if not the entire table).

Comment: I've rerun the query with two indexes, one on `ship_to_id` and another on `price_after_discount`. I've also used `where price_after_discount <> 0` : no significant change in processing time. I ran `explain`: `key` is the `ship_to_id` index, and possible key is the `price_after_discount` index. Interestingly, `rows` is identical to the previous run, when only the `ship_to_id` index was available. @Gordon Linoff: I'll create a composite index and try that out.

Answer (score 2):

If all the orders in that table aren't current (i.e. not going to change again) then you could archive them off into another table to reduce how much data has to be scanned.

Another option is to throw a `last_modified` timestamp on the table with an index. You could then keep track of when the query is run and store the results in another table (`query_results`). When it's time to run the query again, you would only need to select the orders that were modified since the last time the query was run, then use that to update the `query_results`. The logic is a little more complicated, but it should be much faster assuming a low percentage of the orders are updated between query executions.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL *will* use an index for a `group by`, at least according to the documentation, as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-optimization.html).

To be most useful, all the columns used in the query should be in the index.  This prevents the engine from having to reference the original data as well as the index.  So, try an index on `orders(ship_to_id, price_after_discount)`.

Comment: Processing time is the same as with two single indexes. `explain` still shows `key=ship_to_id_index` and `possible_keys=price_after_discount_index`: Doesn't seem as if the composite index was used.

Comment: @user2105469 . . . Out of curiousity, if you replace the `sum()` with `min()`, will the plan then use the index?  I ask, because the query seems to meet the conditions for a "tight index scan", but it is just barely missing the conditions for a "loose index scan".  The `min()`/`max()` restriction should not be necessary for the tight index scan.

Comment: The plan chooses `key=ship_to_id_index` and `possible_keys=price_after_discount_index` for both `min/max` and `sum`. If this has any bearing: there are ~6.5K unique `price_after_discount` values, and ~900K unique 'ship_to_ids'.